# How would I get this 3 tone lighting effect for edges?

Tags: lighting, freestyle, 2d, workbench-render-engine

[image: The effect I want]
I want to get this effect that defines the edges and then colors them with 3 tone coloring, I've tried with freestyle but I want to get the same effect, I think this wad one is workbench

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - I'm not sure it will give exactly the look you have, but it's the closest I can think of.

Start by giving your object a Wireframe Modifier (I made mine extra large in the screenshot so it stands out more). Make sure to un-check "replace original" and set the Material offset to 1 - this will allow you to assign a different material to the wireframe than what's on your base object.

[image: Tricolor1]

Then make sure your object has 2 materials - a base material, and a wireframe material. Make the base material whatever you want, but make the wireframe material look something like this:

[image: Tricolor2]

Obviously you can adjust the ColorRamp to play with the colors. I've also tried other combinations using a Vector Math node and adding inputs such as a "Facing" from a Layer Weight node, which gives some interesting results, but I'm not sure if it's what you are looking for. Maybe use this idea as a base, and play around until you get something you like. (As a head start, try using a Vector Math node to multiply the Normal Vector by the Pointiness factor.)

Comment: thanks, this works great for small models like that on there but with larger-scale ones it does not snap to the edges quite a s well